# TFS 2010 - Area Path Validation

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

We have a scenario where we have put security on work items by using Area Paths.  There is a specific Area Path in which only a Manager group can put work items INTO that area path where a certain group can see those work items and edit them.  However, I need to make it that anyone else (Contributors) can edit the work item as well.  The issue comes when they need to SAVE the work item and it already has this "restricted" area path set.

I have created a "hidden" Area Validation field with the rule of WHEN the SYSTEM.AreaID has a value of "xx", make that restricted, except for the project Managers.

I need everyone else to be able to edit the work item and save it in that area path.

There is a suggestion I received to create another Area Validation field and make System.AreaPath ReadOnly, but that doesn't work.

Here is the current code:

```
<FIELD type="String" name="Area Validation" refname="Agenda.AreaValidation">
    <PROHIBITEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="Restricted" />
    </PROHIBITEDVALUES>
    <WHEN value="32" field="System.AreaId">
      <COPY from="value" value="Restricted" not="[project]\Managers" />
    </WHEN>
    <HELPTEXT>Hidden field used to validate Product Area</HELPTEXT>
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD type="String" name="Area Validation2" refname="Agenda.AreaValidation2">
    <WHEN value="POC/Restricted" field="System.AreaPath">
      <READONLY not="[project]\Managers" />
    </WHEN>
    <HELPTEXT>Hidden field used to validate Product Area</HELPTEXT>
  </FIELD>
```

Thanks!